# UIView with rotation issues

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

I've a sample project, where I'm creating an custom UIViewController.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize webViews = _webViews;
@synthesize webView = _webView;

- (void)setWebView:(UIWebView *)webView {
    if (webView!=_webView) {
        [self.webView removeFromSuperview];
        _webView = nil;
        _webView = webView;
        [self.view addSubview:self.webView];
        [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"]]];
    }
}

- (IBAction)newWebView:(id)sender {
    self.webView = [self.webViews objectAtIndex:1];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    UIWebView *webView1 = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    webView1.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    UIWebView *webView2 = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    webView2.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    self.webViews = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: webView1, webView2, nil];

    self.webView = [self.webViews objectAtIndex:0];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Two *UIWebView*'s are created inside the `viewWillAppear:animated` and stored in an array -- and than the first *UIWebView* is added to the subview of *self.view*. When a button in the navigation bar is pressed, the first *UIWebView* will be removed from the subview and the next one will be added instead.

The problem is, that if I'm running the application in landscape (both iPhone and iPad) after the second *UIWebView* is added, the WebView is not filling the entire screen. Why?

[image]

You can download the small sample project here: http://uploads.demaweb.dk/WebView.zip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know why but this inside your action method will do the trick...

```
UIWebView *newWebView=[[UIWebView alloc] init];
    newWebView=[self.webViews objectAtIndex:1] ;
    newWebView.frame=self.view.frame;
    self.webView = newWebView;
```

hope this helps.. :/